# Airflow Service API to receive external requests from a Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-composer

We are using our own Node.js project to call the Airflow APIs using the package google-auth-library. The project is used to schedule tasks from a custom UI that we have built. The user will be able to string multiple tasks together and the code will call Airflow to run these tasks.

How are we calling Cloud composer -  Using this sample class:

````
import { ServiceUnavailableException } from '@nestjs/common';
const keys = require('../../keys/service-account-key.json');
 
export class AirflowHttpClientService {
  auth: GoogleAuth;
  targetAudience: string;
 
  constructor() {
    this.auth = new GoogleAuth({
      keyFilename:
        '/Users/leogomesdev/projects/onedata-migration-api/keys/service-account-key.json',
      credentials: {
        client_email: keys.client_email,
        private_key: keys.private_key,
      },
      projectId: keys.projectId,
    });
    // this.auth = new GoogleAuth(); // we could use this, but same error occurs
 
    this.targetAudience =
      'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  }
 
  async sendRequest(): Promise<any> {
    const requestWithoutAuth = {
      baseUrl: 'https://ef92ed587683e3d33p-tp.appspot.com',
      url: '/api/v1/dags',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
    };
 
    const authorizedRequest = await this.auth.authorizeRequest(
      requestWithoutAuth,
    );
 
    const client = await this.auth.getIdTokenClient(this.targetAudience);
    return await client
      .request(authorizedRequest)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException(error.message);
      });
  }
}```
 
But we are always receiving this error message as response and we are not able to call the Airflow APIs.
 
```{
    "detail": null,
    "status": 403,
    "title": "Forbidden",
    "type": "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/2.0.1+composer/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Errors/PermissionDenied"
}```
 
We want to have Airflow Service API to receive external requests from a Service Account.
````

Comment: I was reviewing the error and it doesn't help as it doesn't point to a specific permission. You can try to assign the Project Owner role to the service account for ensuring the service account is allowed for everything and run again the code. If this works, then just adjust the permissions since the code is right. If that doesn't work, the problem might be with the code, therefore, if the issue persists, then I recommend you to review and try to follow the example of the public documentation for authentication with Node.js
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code